# Deserialise XML with parameters to object

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I have this simple xml that I just can't deserialise to an object, there are something wrong with my model classes. I just Receive an empty object.

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
\n<response>
\n<lst name=\"responseHeader\">
   <int name=\"status\">0</int>
   <int name=\"QTime\">20596</int>
</lst>\n
</response>\n"
```

i serialize like this:

```
var x = result.Content;     
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(response));              
StringReader rdr = new StringReader(x);
response resultingMessage = 
(response)serializer.Deserialize(rdr);
```

and my model classes look like:

```
[XmlType("response")]
public class response
{
    [XmlElement("responseHeader")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<lst> Lst { get; set; }
}

public class lst
{
    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("int")]
    public List<Int> Int { get; set; }
}

public class Int
{
    [XmlElement("status")]
    public int status { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("QTime")]
    public int QTime { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: And what difficultiy are you facing? Do you get an error? Exception? The `XmlSerializer` is pretty verbose in what hinders him to serialize/deserialize an object.

Comment: did you try removing "/" from your xml before deserializing?

Comment: My difficulty is that i get an empty object.. and i want to get the QTime Value and status value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple things to be corrected.

You need to clean the Xml

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(response));              
StringReader rdr = new StringReader(xmlString.Replace(@"\n",String.Empty).Replace(@"\'","'"));
response resultingMessage = 
(response)serializer.Deserialize(rdr);
```

Secondly, You data structure require some changes. For example, response doesn't require a `name`. It needs to be part of `lst`. Also it is an `attribute`, not an `element`. Hence needs to be decorated with `[XmlAttribute]`

```
[XmlType("response")]
public class response
{
    [XmlElement("lst")]
    public List<lst> Lst { get; set; }
}

public class lst
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("int")]
    public List<Int> Int { get; set; }
}

public class Int
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: I have the structure but still no values

Comment: @LiseOestergaard Please recheck the data structure, there are some changes. Also the Attributes has changed. For example, lst.Name uses [XmlAttribute]

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

```
/*
var x = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<response>\n<lst name=\"responseHeader\"><int name=\"status\">0</int><int name=\"QTime\">20596</int></lst>\n</response>\n";

*/

var x = result.Content;   
 x= x.Replace("\\n", string.Empty).Replace("\\", string.Empty);  
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(response));              
StringReader rdr = new StringReader(x);
response resultingMessage = 
(response)serializer.Deserialize(rdr);
```

sometimes extra characters can cause the conversion issue.